# find_element only works with XPATH

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to make a booking program with selenium and chrome driver. Selenium only finds elements by XPATH and is unable to locate elements with `By.ID`, `By.CSS_SELECTOR` or `By.CLASS_NAME`. I tried expressing it in different forms. Locating by class worked in one of the other files in my program, which is why I am confused.

Here is (what I think) the problematic part of my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
class BookingFiltration():
    def __init__(self, driver:WebDriver):
        self.driver = driver

    def apply_star_rating(self, star_value):
        star_filter_box=self.driver.find_element(By.ID,"filter_group_class_:R14q:")
        star_child_elements = star_filter_box.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '*')

        for star_element in star_child_elements:
            if str(star_element.get_attribute('innerHTML')).strip() == f'{star_value} stars':
                star_element.click()
```

It can't locate elements by ID. Here's what I am trying to locate

[image]

It is connected to the main file where the functions are called and another function definition file.

Here's the relevant part of the latter:

```
import booking.constants as const
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from booking.booking_filtrations import BookingFiltration
import time
#  <...>
    def apply_filtrations(self):
        filtration = BookingFiltration(driver=self)
        filtration.apply_star_rating(star_value=5)
```

Why can't it locate this element (or any at that point) by something other than XPATH? I apologize if the provided code is not enough. I will remake the question if it's neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

What xpath are you using to locate the star filter box? Anyway, I suspect the problem has to due with the id containing the `:` character. I tried this and works

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[id="filter_group_class_:R1cq:"]')
```

Also, since the part between the two `:` may change (in your case is `R14q`, in my case is `R1cq`) you may consider using

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[id*=filter_group_class]')
```

where `*=` means "contains".